# Why doesn't Write-Host "$PSCommandPath" output my current path?

Tags: powershell, path, output

I have the following bit of code-

```
Set-Location "$PSCommandPath"
Write-Host "Starting script."
Write-Host "Current directory is... $PSCommandPath"
```

Which just returns-

```
Starting script.
Current directory is...
```

How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I had to guess, you are running an older version of PowerShell that does not support `$PSCommandPath`.  The variable is only available in versions 3.0 and newer.  From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx):

> `$PSCommandPath`
>
> Contains the full path and name of the script that is being run.
>   This parameter is valid in all scripts. **This automatic variable is
>   introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.**

So, like all undefined variables, `$PSCommandPath` is being treated as `$null`:

```powershell
PS > ($undefined).GetType()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ ($undefined).GetType()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


PS > 
PS > $var = 123
PS > Write-Host "My variable: $var"
My variable: 123

PS > Write-Host "My variable: $undefined"
My variable: 

PS >
```

To fix the problem, you need to upgrade PowerShell to version 3.0 or newer.

---

Also, it seems like you actually want [`Get-Location`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176853.aspx), which returns the current working directory:

```powershell
Write-Host "Current directory is... $(Get-Location)"
```

Comment: I see! Thank you. It appears I'm using PS v2. I don't want to upgrade because I want my script to be compatible with other machines... or will it be backwards compatible?

If not, is there a way to set my default location in PS v2? Get-Location to a variable and then assign Set-Location to that variable? Edit- Aha! It does work!

Comment: As the description say: `Contains the full path and name of the script that is being run.` So if you try to run this from command line it will be **empty** since it's not in a script.